# local Notification + run specific function

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I want to do specific job when app notify means instead of show alert run specific function

is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

In a word: No. Local notifications are intended to alert the user at a specific time. They only way to run code in your application based on a notification is if the user interacts with the notification in such a way that starts your app, usually by clicking the action (or "view") button.

More details can be found under "[Handling Local and Remote Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW4)" in the [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1).

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 4.0

You can handle a local notification like handling push notification.

When the app is launching by tapping the local notification alert view (naturally the app should be ended before).

In the following method,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

please do the following code

```
NSDictionary* dictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
NSLog("%@", dictionary);
```